# necesito ayuda con un componente de vue, infinite loading

Tags: vue.js

he estado aprendiendo laravel y vue de practica estoy haciendo un aplicativo tipo quora, bien, puedo crear y actualizar datos desde dos componentes hijo (ventanas modales)sin ningun problema en el componente padre tengo lo siguiente:

```
  data(){

     return{
          questions: [],
          page: 0,
          errors: [],

         }
      }, 

methods: {


  getquestions: function(){

         var urlQuestions = 'questions';
          axios.get(urlQuestions).then(response=>{
                  this.questions = response.data.data
           });

         },

  created: function(){
          this.getquestions();
         },
```

hasta ahi todo bien, cada vez que agrego y edito una pregunta todo funciona uso un this.$emit('newQuestion');

```
<addquestions v-on:newQuestion="getquestions"></addquestions>
```

pero ahora estoy usando el componente infnite loading

```
infiniteHandler($state){
      this.page++
      let urlQuestions = 'questions?page=' + this.page;
      axios.get(urlQuestions).then(response=>{
        let q = response.data.data
        if(q.length){
           this.questions = this.questions.concat(q);
           $state.loaded()
         }else{
           $state.complete()
         }
      });

     },
```

hasta ahi, el componente funciona bien y pagina los datos con el scroll, mi pregunta es como hago cuando creo una pregunta o la edito para reflejar el cambio de inmediato ya que esta parte no uso el metodo getquestions ni  created? y me toca refrescar el navegador para ver el cambio, gracias espero me entiendan